# GdxFreetype and camera: fonts become blurry

Tags: java, android, libgdx, freetype, bitmap-fonts

I generate my [BitmapFonts](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html) at runtime with [GdxFreetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype). As the `parameter.size` is in pixels and I use a camera which scales up the scene, the font becomes blurry (even with texture filters at higher resolutions).

I need a way to create fonts based on the current resolution. How can I achieve that?

Comment: check if this answers your question  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79487/problem-to-match-font-size-to-the-screen-resolution-in-libgdx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two different cameras! One for your game that could have virtual size(say 16x20) and one pixel perfect camera. Draw those bitmap fonts using the second one. And for dynamically setting parameter size while generating them i personally use

```
 ORIGINAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT/SOME_CONSTANT
```